# Whether scatter can be used to replace web3?

Tags: web3js

Whether I can use scatter instead of web3 metamask? In this way I do not need to add the metamask add on on my browser? And I can run the dapp on mobile for scatter because metamask does not support mobile?

Answer (score 1):

web3 does not require MetaMask. Web3 can be used with any web browser, as long as you have a node that exposes Web3 API  (over http RPC or WebSocket).

Example : https://coursetro.com/posts/code/99/Interacting-with-a-Smart-Contract-through-Web3.js-%28Tutorial%29

Alternatively, you can get a free API endpoint from https://infura.io/